# Accessing specific JSON values in HTML

Tags: html, arrays, json, ajax

I have an AJAX call like this that fetches a library of books:

```
$(function() {
  $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_bookCount',
  function(data) {
    $("#books").text(data.books);
  });
});
```

This produces a JSON result like this, which counts each book according to genre:

```
{
  "books": {
    "mystery": 1, 
    "romance": 2, 
    "horror": 0, 
    "fantasy": 3, 
    "biography": 1
  }
}
```

I want to display the specific counts for each genre in my HTML. This is what I have so far, but I know it's incorrect:

```
<p> <span id="books.mystery"></span> Mysteries<br>
    <span id="books.romance"></span> Romances<br>
    <span id="books.horror"></span> Horrors<br>
    <span id="books.fantasy"></span> Fantasies<br>
    <span id="books.biography"></span> Biographies </p>
```

This doesn't work/display anything obviously and I know it's probably a simple question, but I'm new to this and I don't know the right way to do it. How can I access specific values from this JSON result and put them in my HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are assigning data is completely wrong.

Try this:

```
$(function() {
  $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_bookCount',
  function(data) {
    $.each(data.books, function(key, val) {
      $("#books\\." + key).text(val);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Needs to be  `$("#books\\." + key)` for jQuery to parse the period.

Comment: @Mojtaba Your answer is great, thank you! It's just missing a closing parentheses and semicolon for the $.each part, but I added that and it works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: @Mojtaba Quick follow up. How would I loop through a json array if I didn't know the key names beforehand?

Comment: @Sarah, I fixed the missed part. I wrote it here on the fly. And about your question, according to the code you provided, the loop iterates the keys automatically. However, I strongly recommend you to do some exercises with loops, jQuery selectors, and objects.

Comment: @Mojtaba I meant in the HTML-- how would I refer to the keys if I don't know them? And yes, I'll definitely take your advice..i'm new to jQuery/ajax